# How to build a select menu in cogs?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I finally found a solution.
Here is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands
async def select_callback(interaction: discord.Interaction):
result = interaction.data.get('values')
result = result[0]
print(result)
if result == '1':
    await interaction.response.send_message("success1")
elif result == '2':
    await interaction.response.send_message('success2')
elif result == '3':
    await interaction.response.send_message("success3")


class aButton(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @app_commands.command(name = "view_base", description = "Simple View Example")
    async def view_base(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        view = discord.ui.View()
        select1 = discord.ui.Select()
        select1.add_option(label="A", value = 1, description="Explain a")
        select1.add_option(label="B", value = 2, description="Explain B")
        select1.add_option(label="C", value = 3, description="Explain C")
        select1.callback = select_callback
        view.add_item(select1)
        await interaction.response.send_message(view = view)


async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(aButton(bot))
```

When I use select menu, it is always **Interaction failed**.

I guess there's some problems in the callback.u.

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: Please do not put your solution in your question and instead accept an answer if it solved your problem or post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Select.callback](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.ui.Select.callback) only takes one argument: `interaction`.

```
async def select_callback(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    ...
```

`self` is conventionally a parameter taken by class methods; where self is the class object.

The `select` parameter only exists when using the [discord.ui.select](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#id2) decorator.

```
class SelectView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
    @discord.ui.select(...)
    async def select_callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, select: discord.ui.Select):
        ...
```

For more: [Select](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#select), [View](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#view)